# PHP file with multiple lines to array and key with value

Tags: php

I have files with lines in it where i want to create array with a key and value

file1 has for example:

```
thisisline = aline
thisisalsoaline = oke
whereiamaline = check

file2 has 
thisisline = aline
thisisalsoaline = oke
whereiamaline = checker
```

what i am trying to create but no luck to have a result which is :(

```
thisisline => aline
thisisalsoaline => oke
whereiamaline => check
```

i tried with explode but then it was like

```
[0] => thisisline = aline
```

the endgoal is to have 2 files to compare with array_diff_key so that i can identify the line whereiamaline = checker

Could somebody point me to the correct direction?

Thank you

Comment: *"i tried with explode"* show us how you did that

Comment: `file` function will give you lines. `explode` by `=` will give you array. Also `parse_ini_file` will do both.

Comment: i tried with for example
```
$file1 = parse_ini_file("file2.txt");
$file2 = parse_ini_file("file1.txt");

print_r(array_diff_key($file1, $file2));

Answer (score 1):

Your files look like ini-files. php already has `parse_ini_file` function, which will return `key => value` array.

Next, correct function is [`array_diff_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php):

```
$a = parse_ini_file('file1');
$b = parse_ini_string('file2');

print_r(array_diff_assoc($a, $b));
```

Because `array_diff_key` returns keys which are in first array, but not in second, which is not your case.

Comment: Prevent what exaclty? Have you opened the manual? There's a third argument with possible values `INI_SCANNER_RAW` / `INI_SCANNER_TYPED`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
foreach(file("file1.txt") as $line) {
    $pieces = explode("=", $line);
//Do whatever you want to do with $pieces here. $pieces[0] and $pieces[1]
//Trim the values of $pieces too.
}
```

Another way is:

```
for each(file("file1.txt") as $line) {
$res[] = array_map('trim', explode('=', $line));
}
```

This one will directly populate the $res[] array with arrays of each line (which are trimmed)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `explode` function with delimeter `=`, like:

```
$finall_array = array();
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $le = explode("=",$line);
        $finall_array[$le[0]] = $le[1];
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // here goes error file opeping
}
```

Then just use $final_array like your output

Answer (score 0):

So i used the parse_in_file together with the arra_diff_assoc and then it is

```
<?php 
$file1 = parse_ini_file("master_manager.txt");
$file2 = parse_ini_file("master_manager1.txt");
echo "<pre>"; 
$myarray = array_diff_assoc($file1, $file2); 
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value){ 
echo $key." = ".$value."\n"; } 
echo "</pre>";
```

but then if a line contains false or true it gives a 1 or nothing (null) how to prevent that? –